# Spring Boot: Serving aggregated data from a websocket connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'd like to make a RESTful web app with Spring Boot that would be constantly receiving information from a websocket connection, aggregating it, and serving those aggregated data via its REST API.

So I'll need to open and maintain a WebSocket connection, while also running `SpringApplication.run()` in the `main()` function.

The `@Scheduled` annotation seems to only run tasks at a specific time or interval, but doesn't seem to have a way to always run something in the background.

What is a sensible way to achieve what I've described?

Comment: You can run it in a separate thread when starting the application ( start the socket after application is ready, use CommandLineRunner .. ) and then store your data (in memory or in data storage ) and then serve it using your Rest API

Answer (score 0):

Just have your application connect to a socket on application startup

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication 
implements CommandLineRunner {

private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
  .getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    //Connect to socket and cache the results if you want to
}}
```

Spring Boot will automatically call the run method of all beans implementing this interface after the application context has been loaded

for more information about command line runner you can visit https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `WebSocketClient` provided by Spring? After you connect you will get notified via a callback method each time a new websocket frame is received.

You can follow the example here https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client

Just put it in a class annotated with `@Component` or `@Service` that starts the websocket session through the constructor.

You won't need to do the `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()` since you have a server that is always running.